# Java: Best way to find word in alphabetic sorted text file

Tags: java, text-files, binary-search, alphabetical

I've got this huge alphabetically sorted index and I need to get the lines for specific terms. Reading the file line by line and checking if I got the right term does not seem efficient to me, hence the size of the index (we indexed the english wikipedia corpus).

Therefor I am looking for a way to do a binary search on the lines. I use the LineNumberReader to efficiently get the number of lines, but there seems to be no efficient solution to get the n'th line from a file.

I am wondering if reading lines until I am at the n'th line, checking if it is the right term and take action according to a binary search algorithm (possibly reading the lines again because I need a line I already skipped) is more efficient then just checking terms line by line?

Any other suggestions are also very welcome!

Note that I need to get a set of lines, depending on the set of terms to search for.

Comment: Note that [`LineNumberReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) does not claim to efficiently index the file or get the number of lines. It merely reports the current line number as it reads the file linearly.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you should use a database - they benefit from many years of careful engineering related to indexed queries on large datasets, which you are unlikely to be able to come anywhere near to if you roll your own.

If you really wanted to do this yourself you'd need to create two separate indexes:

- An index of word -> line number(s) containing the term so you can quickly calculate the set of line numbers containing a given search term
- An index of line number -> position in file so you can quickly retrieve the right line via random access

Furthermore, if your data set is really large then both of these *indexes could themselves be larger than memory*. So you'd have to implement a disk based index - something like a [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). At which point you'll be reinventing most of the RDBMS wheel and probably kicking yourself for not using a proper database in the first place.

Consider trying [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) - It's open source, extremely mature and well maintained and has pretty decent text search capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will definitely consider it!

Answer (score 1):

Reading the file line by line will be inefficient, yes, especially with the size of the corpus you are using. Have you considered indexing the data in something other than a flat file? Like a database that can be queried? Or using a tool like Lucene to index and search the data?